# Including a Many-To-Many EF Child Relationship in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, odata, automapper

I'm working on an API that uses EF 6, AutoMapper, and Odata. We've got a call that uses a custom Linq query in the repository rather than relying on conventions, but we need to add a child collection that has a many-to-many relationship. I've set up many-to-many in EF before (adding HasMany...WithTable to the config of the model, adding the collections to the data and view models, mapping accordingly) and have done the same steps in this situation. However, the closest thing I can get to the desired behavior is getting a blank child object using Odata's $expand feature (it's the correct object, but empty).  This indicates to me that the configuration is correct from the standpoint of OData and Automapper but not with EF.

Here's what the method in the repo looks like without anything related to the child collection included (I'm shortening it for clarity):

```
public static IQueryable<Measure> GetEligibleMeasures(this IRepository<Measure> repository,
        string projectId)
    {
      var measures = repository.GetRepository<Measure>().Queryable();
      var projects = repository.GetRepository<PROJECT>().Queryable();
      //More Repositories...

      var eligibleMeasures = (from m in measures
                              join p in projects on m.PROJECTID equals p.PROJECTID
                              //more joins and where clauses
                              select m
                              ).Distinct();

      return eligibleMeasures;
    }
```

What I need is to be able to return a Sites collection with a many-to-many relationship with Measures. I've tried throwing Include in there in a few different places (in the from, before the distinct, and in the return) but come up with nothing. I've also tried scrapping the standard has-many-through config and using the linking table as an entity, then adding two joins to the query to get to the child collection and using an include to attempt to load it. None of that worked either.

Does anyone have any experience with this or suggestions on what to do? I can post parts of the config if that helps - there are just so many factors between the three big tech pieces that I am not sure what to post initially.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do many-to-many mappings in your ORM, map join tables explicitly:

https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/

Then your problems go away.